# Program causes infinite loop

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the program in question. Why is it causing an infinite loop?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Workshop
{
public:
    int pictureFrames( vector<int> pieces );
};

int Workshop::pictureFrames( vector<int> pieces )
{
    int count = 0;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < pieces.size() - 2 ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < (pieces.size() - 1) ; j++ )
        {
            for ( int k = j + 1; k < (pieces.size()); k++ )
            {
                bool possible = (pieces[i] + pieces[j] > pieces[k]) &&
                                (pieces[j] + pieces[k] > pieces[i]) &&
                                (pieces[k] + pieces[i] > pieces[j]);
                if ( possible )
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void main()
{
    Workshop w;
    vector<int> pieces;
    pieces.push_back( 100 );
    w.pictureFrames( pieces );
}
```

Comment: In the future, format your code by highlighting it and pressing `CTRL+K` or by indenting four spaces. Do not surround each line with backticks. Secondly, [`void main` isn't a valid signature in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). Thirdly, since you are using Visual Studio, take advantage of the built-in debugging tools (i.e by setting breakpoints) to see where the fault in your program lies.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself? I recommend putting debug printouts at suitable points

Comment: See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29de5a6cd9bd21e

Answer (score 3):

The `size()` method for vector returns `size_t` which is an unsigned type. When you take an unsigned type with value `1` and subtract 2 from it, you will get a very large number.

If you put the following line inside the `pictureFrames` method, you will observe why the loop is taking so long to execute.

```
cout << pieces.size() - 2 << endl;,
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compile it with full diagnostics?

See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29de5a6cd9bd21e

```
main.cpp:15:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]

for ( int i = 0 ; i < pieces.size() - 2 ; i++ )

                  ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[two repeats for the inner loops, and a complaint about `void main()`]

The diagnostics are quite instructive.

The `int` is promoted to `unsigned long` (or whatever `size_t` is), and compared with `pieces.size() - 2`, which *due to modulo-arithmetic* is **really big**.